# Webpack intermittent react Jenkins build with javascript errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jenkins, webpack

My project environment is , React with redux and redux-saga , webpack 
Jenkins is used for CI/CD
since a month , we are getting a strange issue, the Jenkins (webpack) build & deployment is successful however when I access the portal it shows a blank page because of below Javascript error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: saga is not defined
at Module.1148 (main.44c97d10353333934fe5.bundle.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (manifest.6a34ff8be70a737e5aa6.bundle.js:1)
at Object.646 (main.44c97d10353333934fe5.bundle.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (manifest.6a34ff8be70a737e5aa6.bundle.js:1)
at checkDeferredModules (manifest.6a34ff8be70a737e5aa6.bundle.js:1)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (manifest.6a34ff8be70a737e5aa6.bundle.js:1)
at vendor.fef8d73f71dc764a97a1.bundle.js:1
```

when looked at the failing file in code base the sagas.js file has "export default sagas" , so the s in sagas is truncated during build process hence the javascript error

After re-running the same build in Jenkins then it is producing a clean build and application works normally without above error

and strangely this behaviour doesn't occur on every build it is intermittent

another error similar to this is

[built version of utag.js with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCHOy.png)

[actual version of utag.js from code base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er2qU.png)

The main issue is I couldn't replicate the issue locally , I have run the webpack build on the  branch which resulted in javascript error - but no luck , everytime webpack produced a clean build locally

Here are my config files

Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --inline --progress --env development --config webpack/dev.config.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack --env production --config webpack/prod.config.js",
    "build:test": "webpack --env test --config webpack/prod.config.js",
    "stylelint": "stylelint '**/*.scss', '**/*.css'",
    "stylelint:silentexit": "stylelint '**/*.scss', '**/*.css'; exit 0",
    "jslint": "eslint . --fix",
    "jslint:silentexit": "eslint .; exit 0",
    "test": "npm run jslint && npm run test:unit",
    "test:unit": "jest --colors",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --passWithNoTests",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage -u --colors",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook",
    "generateSvgIconComponents": "styled-svg src/icons/*.svg --size=small:18x18 --size=medium:24x24 --size=large:36x36"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 10",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@rebass/components": "^4.0.0-1",
    "acorn": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.2.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.5.2",
    "fixed-data-table-2": "^0.8.26",
    "glamor": "^2.20.40",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "javascript-excel": "^1.0.3",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-react": "^1.0.10",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.6.0",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-compound-slider": "^2.3.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.1.1",
    "react-data-export": "^0.5.0",
    "react-draggable": "^4.0.3",
    "react-list-drag-and-drop": "^0.9.1",
    "react-markdown": "^4.2.2",
    "react-pdf": "^4.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.10.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.21.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.4",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.1",
    "styled-system": "^4.2.4",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^4.1.18",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "eslint": "^5.14.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.1",
    "jest-react-hooks-mock": "^1.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "pdf2json": "^1.1.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-saga-testing": "^1.0.5",
    "sinon": "^7.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "styled-svg": "^2.4.7",
    "stylelint": "^9.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.3.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack": "4.41.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.1"
  }
}
```

webpack/base.config.js

```js
'use strict'
const path = require('path')

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const dirName = __dirname.replace('webpack','');
const util = require('./util'); 

// cleans 'dist' folder everytime before a new build
const cleanPLugin = env => (new CleanWebpackPlugin({
  root: path.join(dirName, util.getRootContext(env) ),
  verbose: true,
  dry: false
}));

const AnalyzerPlugin = new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(
  {
    analyzerMode: 'none'
  }
);

const copyWebpackPlugin = env => (  new CopyPlugin([ {
    from : path.join(dirName, 'src/assets/static'),
    to :  path.join(dirName, `dist/${util.getRootContext(env)}/assets`)
  }, {
    from : path.join(dirName, 'src/assets/pages'),
    to :  path.join(dirName, `dist/${util.getRootContext(env)}`)
  }
]));

const HTMLPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.join(dirName, 'src/scripts/index.html'),
  chunksSortMode: 'none'
});

module.exports = (env) => {
  // BUILDING WEBPACK
  const config = {};
 
    config.plugins = [cleanPLugin(env), AnalyzerPlugin, HTMLPlugin, copyWebpackPlugin(env)]
  
    config.entry = ["whatwg-fetch", "babel-polyfill", path.join(dirName, '/src/scripts/index.js')]
  
    config.output = {
      path: path.join(dirName, '/dist'),
      filename: '[name].build.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    }

    config.module = {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|ttf|woff2)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {}
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg/,
          use: {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(css|less)$/,
          use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        }
      ]
    }

    config.resolve = {
      extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css' ],
      alias: {
        DesignSystem: path.resolve(dirName, 'src/design-system/'),
        Icons: path.resolve(dirName, 'src/icons/'),
        Scripts: path.resolve(dirName, 'src/scripts/'),
        CMS: path.resolve(dirName, 'cms/'),
      }
    }

    config.node = { fs: 'empty' }
    return config

}
```

webpack/prod.config.js

```js
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./base.config.js');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('./util');

const dirName = __dirname.replace('webpack','');
module.exports = env => (merge(baseConfig(env),
    {
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
              cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                  test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                  name: 'vendor',
                  chunks: 'initial'
                }
              }
            },
            runtimeChunk: {
              name: 'manifest'
            },
            minimizer: [
              new UglifyJsPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                  ecma: 8,
                  mangle: false,
                  keep_classnames: true,
                  keep_fnames: true
                }
              })
            ]
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(dirName, `./dist/${util.getRootContext(env)}`),
            publicPath: `/${util.getRootContext(env)}/`,
            chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',
            filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js'
        },
        mode: 'production'
    }

));
```

```
npm run build:prod is the command which runs this build
```

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!